# How can I change the application size in other classes not mainwindow class?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to change the mainwindow or the native app size width x height in other class not in the mainwindow class. How can I do this?

```
void OptionsDialog::resetWindowLayoutClicked(QResizeEvent* event) {
    QMainWindow::resize(640, 483);
}
```

This is my first try but with no happiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a signal and connect it to a slot in the main window.

For example:

```
class OptionsDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void resize(int w, int h);
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots: 
    void resizeRequest(int w, int h);
};

void OptionsDialog::resetWindowLayoutClicked(QResizeEvent* event) 
{
    emit resize(640, 483);
}
```

When you create the OptionsDialog, connect the signal like this:

```
OptionsDialog* d = new OptionsDialog(this);
connect(d, SIGNAL(resize(int,int)), this, SLOT(resizeRequest(int,int)));
```

And implement the slot:

```
void MainWindow::resizeRequest(int w, int h)
{
    resize(w, h);
}
```

Comment: after the connection to the button or before ?

Comment: You connect you button in the constructor of OptionsDialog, right? If you don't show the dialog until you connect the resizeRequest slot, it doesn't matter which one is connected first.

Comment: can i send you the complete source code ? i have many trouble to get it work

Comment: is the mainwindow::resizeRequest a private or public slot ?

Comment: I intentionally wrote private. If you are creating MainWindow and OptionsWindow from a third class and you want to connect the slot there, you need it public.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get pointer to main window class i assume and change it from that, try passing pointer to it in new class constructor.

```
public OptionsDialog(const QMainWindow * mainWindow) { // class constructor
    m_qWinPtr = mainWindow // this is some class member
}

void OptionsDialog::resetWindowLayoutClicked(QResizeEvent* event) {
    m_qWinPtr->resize(640, 483);
}
```

Comment: That won't work with a pointer to a const though. You may want to use a const pointer, but even better would be to use one of the smart pointer classes (either std or Qt's).